# Javascript Gmaps Zoom Function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

Hi I am trying to create a function where I ask the user to input the zoom value that he wants the map to zoom in but it seems that this is not working. Any advice on it ? Thanks.

```
 function zoomto()
 {
map.SetOptions({zoom: parseInt(prompt('zoom value'))});
 }
```

and here is my button

```
  <input type="button" id="zoomto" value="zoom" onclick="zoomto()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function zoomto() {
    map.set('zoom', parseInt(prompt('zoom value')));
}
```